# Android Room Paging3 correct approach for dynamic filtering

Tags: android, android-room, android-paging-3

I am investigating the new Android Room Paging library

```
   implementation "androidx.paging:paging-runtime-ktx:3.0.0-alpha09"
```

My source database tables approx 10,000 rows and I filter by the first character of the name field as follows:-

DAO

```
@Query("SELECT * from citation_style WHERE citation_style_name LIKE :startsWith ORDER BY citation_style_name ASC")
fun fetch(startsWith: String): PagingSource<Int, CitationStyleDO>
```

Repository

```
fun fetch(startsWith: String): Flow<PagingData<CitationStyleDO>> {
    return Pager(
        PagingConfig(pageSize = 60, prefetchDistance = 30, enablePlaceholders = false, maxSize = 200)
    ) { database.citationStyleDao().fetch("$startsWith%") }.flow
}
```

ViewModel

```
fun fetch(startsWith: String): Flow<PagingData<CitationStyleDO>> {
    return repository.fetch(startsWith).cachedIn(viewModelScope)
}
```

Fragment

```
override fun onStartsWithClicked(startsWith: String) {
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        viewModel.fetch(startsWith).collectLatest { adapter.submitData(it) }
    }
}
```

Is this the correct approach of repeatedly using `lifecycleScope.launch {...}` each time the Starts With character is changed?

Should I be `map{}` or `switchMap{}` triggered by a `MutabaleLiveData<String>` for StartwWith?

Answer (score 9):

This won't work, because submitData doesn't return until `PagingData` is invalidated. You might run into race scenarios where you have multiple jobs launched where `PagingDataAdapter` is trying to collect from multiple `PagingData`.

The more "Flow" way would be to turn your fetch calls into a flow and combine that with your `Flow<PagingData>`, which will automatically propagate cancellation every time your query changes.

A couple other things:

It's recommended to let Paging do the filtering for you, as this way you can avoid re-fetching from DB every time your search changes, and also you can lean on Paging to handle configuration changes and restore state.

You should use `viewLifecycleOwner` instead of `lifecycleScope` directly, because you don't want paging to do work after the fragment's view is destroyed

e.g.,

ViewModel

```
val queryFlow = MutableStateFlow("init_query")
val pagingDataFlow = Pager(...) {
        dao.pagingSource()
    }.flow
    // This multicasts, to prevent combine from refetching
    .cachedIn(viewModelScope)
    .combine(queryFlow) { pagingData, query -> 
        pagingData.filter { it.startsWith(query)
    }
    // Optionally call .cachedIn() here a second time to cache the filtered results.
```

Fragment

```
override fun onStartsWithClicked(startsWith: String) {
    viewModel.queryFlow = startsWith
}

override fun onViewCreated(...) {
     viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
viewModel.pagingDataFlow.collectLatest { adapter.submitData(it) }
}
```

Note: You can definitely use Room to do the filtering if you want, probably the right way there is to `.flatMapLatest` on the queryFlow and return a new `Pager` each tine, and pass the query term to dao function that returns a `PagingSource`

ViewModel

```
queryFlow.flatMapLatest { query ->
    Pager(...) { dao.pagingSource(query) }
        .cachedIn(...)
}
```

Comment: How about filtering and as well doing an api call? I'm guessing you can do an api call that  saves the response to the DB which is still later emitted to the PagingSource

Comment: What do you mean by API call here? Do you mean remote fetch for more items? Those happen on separate layers in paging so it doesn't change how you would apply the filter operator in the example in my answer.

Comment: The problem with combine here is that pages that have been dropped will not be filtered right? so the only way to filter everything is letting room do the filtering

Comment: @DennisVA if a page is dropped it won't be visible in UI, if it gets re-inserted it the filter transform will run again. PagingData transforms are incremental so you never have to worry about them "missing" a page.